# How to retrieve metadata content of an item from another item input form in dspace 5 xmlui

Tags: dspace

I have two collections (meetings and decisions) that are related to one another. Decisions are based on meetings, I therefore would like to show this relationship in decisions metadata by having a link with the meeting title that links to meeting item. How would i go about implementing this on a custom input form e.g with dropdown or choice management that enables a submitter to simply select the meeting while imputing decision metadata.

Comment: I do not believe that there is a way to relate 2 items via a dropdown as you describe.  Perhaps you could assign a meeting id value in metadata to both the meeting and the decision.  You could then create a custom facet based on the meeting id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not such an easy task. I'm sure there are many ways to do this but they involve a lot of custom code.
Here is what I would do in xmlui.

1. index the meeting metadata in discovery
2. write a cocoon reader that queries discovery and returns json
3. write javascript to call this endpoint and insert the options on the page

Each of these are worth their own share of stackoverflow questions though. But if you're up to it, here are classes and examples to get you started.

1. [SolrServiceIndexPlugin.java](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/discovery/SolrServiceIndexPlugin.java) (implement & configure in spring)
2. [JSONControlledVocabularyReader.java](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/cocoon/JSONControlledVocabularyReader.java) (implement your own & configure in a sitemap.xmap)
3. I couldn't really find an easy javascript example in the dspace submission... maybe [person-lookup.js](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/static/js/person-lookup.js) or [vocabulary-support.js](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/static/js/vocabulary-support.js)

Then again maybe there are more practical approaches.